# dynamic TableLayout refresh in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

Hy all!
I have this TableLayout and the screen is empty after creating. I have no xml file because of the specification that the number of rows and columns is given manual. First I have to fill the table with empty 1 x 1 not visible TextView-s, because this solution has to be used if I want to add a button at cordinates (k, l) where k <=rows and l <=columns.
The code is the following:

```
package hu.harge;

import java.awt.Button;

import javax.swing.text.TableView.TableRow;

import sun.jkernel.Bundle;

public class AccessibleLayoutActivity extends Activity {

    private int rows, columns;
    private TableLayout tl = null;
    private ScrollView sv;

    public void createView(int rows, int columns) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.sv = new ScrollView(this);

        tl = new TableLayout(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tr.addView(tv);
                tv.setMaxHeight(1);
                tv.setMaxWidth(1);

            }
            tl.addView(tr);

        }

        sv.addView(tl, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        this.setContentView(sv);
    }

    public void putButton(int row, int column, final String label) {
        if (tl != null) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (row <= rows && column <= columns) {

                Button b = new Button(this);
                b.setText(label);
                TableRow tr = (TableRow) tl.getChildAt(row - 1);
                tr.removeViewAt(column - 1);
                tr.addView(b, column - 1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }
        }

    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        createView(6, 3);

        putButton(1, 3, "Exit");
        putButton(2, 1, "Menu");

    }
}
```

ListView can not be a solution for my problem I think.

The problem is that nothing's shining on the screen.

thanks for the answers:
Geri

Comment: So, what is your actual problem? P.S.: Could you please try to better format your code in the future? I just fixed it for this post.

Comment: @Henrik You're right, the description of the problem wasn't fully understandable so I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I see here many errors:
first,

```
tr.addView(b, column - 1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

should be changed to

```
tr.addView(b, column - 1, new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

The class of layoutparams should always have such prefix, according to the class of the element's parent.

Further, I don't see where you set any layouts for TableRow's or the table, or any of tv. Any View should have set height and width. Always.

If it won't help (you can have other errors, too), better start using layouts from XMLs, make them work and later move them to code one after one. And check the functionality on every step. Also give all elements some background to see them. And makt them for debugging time a bit larger - again, to see them better... as a wolf in Red Hat :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doc says:
The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.